# Search and selectively remove tasks from Celery

Tags: python, redis, celery

I want to clean up my celery queues. How can I search the tasks by their types arguments and the selectively remove some of them? I am using Redis as a broker if that matters; I prefer to not deal with this at the Redis level though.

Answer (score 1):

The only option I see here is using coding directly using the [Kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu) library that is what Celery uses as AMQP a library that can dialogue with all the supported broker in an abstract way including Redis.
I will anyway discourage this practice as often the need of cleanup queue is an outcome of bad design.

Regards

Comment: Agreed, it was some bad design/implementation that added stuff to queues that should not have been added. The fixed code does not do that.